# Calculating weighted average using grouped .agg in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to calculate, by group, the mean of one column and the weighted mean of another column in a dataset using the `.agg()` function within **pandas**. I am aware of a few solutions, but they aren't very concise.

One solution has been posted here ([pandas and groupby: how to calculate weighted averages within an agg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714555/pandas-and-groupby-how-to-calculate-weighted-averages-within-an-agg), but it still doesn't seem very flexible because the weights column is hard coded in the lambda function definition. I'm looking to create a syntax closer to this:

```
(
df
.groupby(['group'])
.agg(avg_x=('x', 'mean'),
     wt_avg_y=('y', 'weighted_mean', weights='weight')
)
```

Here is a fully worked example with code that seems needlessly complicated:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'y': [5, 6, 7, 8],
    'weights': [0.75, 0.25, 0.75, 0.25]
})
df
#>>>    group   x   y   weights
#>>> 0      a   1   5   0.75
#>>> 1      a   2   6   0.25
#>>> 2      b   3   7   0.75
#>>> 3      b   4   8   0.25

# aggregation logic
summary = pd.concat(
    [
        df.groupby(['group']).x.mean(),
        df.groupby(['group']).apply(lambda x: np.average(x['y'], weights=x['weights']))
    ], axis=1
)
# manipulation to format the output of the aggregation
summary = summary.reset_index().rename(columns={'x': 'avg_x', 0: 'wt_avg_y'})

# final output
summary
#>>>    group   avg_x   wt_avg_y
#>>> 0      a   1.50    5.25
#>>> 1      b   3.50    7.25
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate weighted average using a pandas/dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205922/calculate-weighted-average-using-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: No because it requires two separate calculations one with an .agg and another with .apply for the weighted average.

Answer (score 8):

Using the `.apply()` method on the entire DataFrame was the simplest solution I could arrive to that does *not* hardcode the column name inside the function definition.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'y': [5, 6, 7, 8],
    'weights': [0.75, 0.25, 0.75, 0.25]
})

summary = (
    df
    .groupby(['group'])
    .apply(
        lambda x: pd.Series([
            np.mean(x['x']),
            np.average(x['y'], weights=x['weights'])
        ], index=['avg_x', 'wt_avg_y'])
    )
    .reset_index()
)
# final output
summary
#>>>    group   avg_x   wt_avg_y
#>>> 0      a   1.50    5.25
#>>> 1      b   3.50    7.25
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
grouped = df.groupby('group')

def wavg(group):
    group['mean_x'] = group['x'].mean()
    group['wavg_y'] = np.average(group['y'], weights=group.loc[:, "weights"])
    return group

grouped.apply(wavg)
```

Comment: This is the solution that I linked to. It hard codes the weights column in the function definition. I would prefer to pass them in as an argument. I think the problem is hard to solve because agg only operations on a single column at a time.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't see that you linked it. Indeed, egg is acting on a single column. One can play around with apply tho. Something like this: ```grouped = df.groupby('group')

def wa(group):
    return group['x'].mean(),np.average(group['y'], weights=group.loc[:, "weights"])
grouped.apply(wa)``` It returns a tuple tho and not two columns. But maybe there is a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Since your weights sum to `1` within groups, you can assign a new column and groupby as usual:

```
(df.assign(wt_avg_y=df['y']*df['weights'])
  .groupby('group')
  .agg({'x': 'mean', 'wt_avg_y':'sum', 'weights':'sum'})
  .assign(wt_avg_y=lambda x: x['wt_avg_y']/ x['weights'])
)
```

Output:

```
         x  wt_avg_y  weights
group                        
a      1.5      5.25      1.0
b      3.5      7.25      1.0
```

Comment: @StevenM.Mortimer see update for a solution that does not requires `weights` adding up to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["weights"]=df["weights"].div(df.join(df.groupby("group")["weights"].sum(), on="group", rsuffix="_2").iloc[:, -1])
df["y"]=df["y"].mul(df["weights"])

res=df.groupby("group", as_index=False).agg({"x": "mean", "y": "sum"})
```

Outputs:

```py
  group    x     y
0     a  1.5  5.25
1     b  3.5  7.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Steven M. Mortimer's solution is clean and easy to read. Alternatively, one could use dict notation inside pd.Series() such that the index= argument is not needed. This provides slightly better readability in my opinion.

```
summary = (
    df
    .groupby(['group'])
    .apply(
        lambda x: pd.Series({
            'avg_x' : np.mean(x['x']),
            'wt_avg_y':  np.average(x['y'], weights=x['weights'])
        }))
    .reset_index()
)
```